# Why can't sort() be used chained on *ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I was trying to sort the results angular brings back from an API on the HTML. `.sort()` works as long as I don't pass any arguments to it. But, since I don't pass arguments it won't sort the array.

This is my Data:

```
[{ "id": "string", "name":"string"},
 { "id": "string", "name":"string"},
 { "id": "string", "name":"string"}]
```

I would like when angular renders the Interpolation that the results are sorted by the key "name" in ascending order.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let label of labels.slice().sort()">{{label.name}} </div>
```

TS won't accept any arguments passed to `.sort()` while in the HTML.

I tried using this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let label of labels.slice().sort((a,b)=> (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))">{{label.name}} </div>
```

This gives an error:

```
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column # in [let lable of labels.slice().sort((a,b)=> (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))] in
```

and also

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token =, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column # in [let label of labels.players.slice().sort((a,b)=> (a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1))] in
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe this is the limitation of Angular binding syntax, so you won't be able to call JS function inside *ngFor directive. I would recommend that you slice and sort your array in your Angular Component Typescript file instead of HTML

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do any data manipulation in your TypeScript code rather than inside of a prop in your template. My guess for the error is that the parser doesn't support the full version of JavaScript in the area where you put it.

It's been years since I've worked with Angular, so I can't give you the exact code, but here's what you need to do:

- Create a new state variable called `sortedLabels`
- Any time `labels` is updated, set the value of `sortedLabels` to a sorted slice of it. Bonus points if Angular supports derived state to do this kind of thing automatically
- Update your template to `<div *ngFor="let label of sortedLabels">{{label.name}} </div>`

if you don't have any issues with `labels` itself being sorted, just do that in your TypeScript code instead of having state with duplicated information.